# "James flicked a peanut at her." — What can "flicked" mean here?

Tags: meaning

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/flick_1):

> to flick something — to hit something lightly with a sudden quick movement, especially using your finger and thumb together, or your hand:
> **(1)** *James flicked a peanut at her*.

After reading the definition of "flick", I still couldn't understand what (1) means.
What can "flicked" mean in (1)?

Comment: Not really sure what your confusion is - the definition you posted is accurate for this situation. James used his finger to propel a peanut at her.

Comment: It's important to understand that flick can mean EITHER flicking "WITH THE TIP OF YOUR **FINGER**" -> what superman is doing in the video below ***OR*** it can simply mean throwing something (say, a football) but only using your wrist motion, not your whole arm.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The most common way to 'flick' a small object like a peanut or pea is to place it onto a flat surface and then to use your middle finger to propel it.

I would imagine that James either placed the peanut in the palm of his hand, or onto a desk or table.

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>He upends a bowl of peanuts on the bar. Then, with malicious pleasure, he begins flipping them, one at a time, at the rows of glasses stacked up on the shelf behind the bar. Ping: Crash! Ping! Crash!</sup></sub>

Comment: It's not just the fast finger movement (often index finger, as well as middle), but _how_ the speed is achieved: by pressing hard against some restraining force (such as the thumb, or the table in the video), and then removing it (e.g. by releasing the thumb, or lifting above the table surface) so that the finger moves a a _very_ high speed for a moment.

Comment: Index finger is more usual than middle finger, in my experience.

Comment: @MikeB - When flicking a heavy item like a peanut, the middle finger gets more power

Comment: I think if I had to flick a peanut I would definitely not "place it on a flat surface". I would place it directly on my thumb.

Comment: @Stef - If you're blessed with flat thumbs...

Comment: @MikeB Interesting. When I saw the video in gotube’s answer, my immediate thought was the opposite: I would always use the middle finger like Reeve does here, never the index finger. Now I’m wondering if there are index- and middle-fingered people just like there are left- and right-handed people.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I would always use a middle finger to flick an actual peanut.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I wonder if it's a culture thing, kinda like which 3 fingers you put up.

Answer (score 42):

That dictionary description is accurate, but it's such a specific action, you really have to see it:

[image: young man flicks a small cracker]

<sub>([Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sODZ5.gif))</sub>

It's not a peanut, but you get the idea.

Comment: In this instance, I think you're incorrect. The way to flick a peanut would be to rest it flat on your palm

Comment: @Richard You’re right that you wouldn’t normally hold a single peanut between your fingers for flicking, but where you place the peanut doesn’t really matter. It’s the sudden, quick movement of the index or middle finger that makes it a flick, and the video clearly shows that. The peanut may have been on a table, in his palm, on the back of his hand, on his arm, on the arm of his chair, or anywhere else.

Comment: @Richard: The point you're making is not part of what the example sentence tries to convey, nor what the meaning of "to flick" is. It does not matter how the flicked object is held in position (if at all) before flicking it.

Answer (score 2):

To "flick" something is to throw it with minimal motion of the arm. Often it will be just a bending of the wrist towards one's torso, and then a rapid motion of the wrist away from the torso, in the direction of the target. Visibly, it's just the hand and the wrist creating the motion; the elbow angle doesn't change except by a couple of degrees; visibly the lower arm does not appear to flex at the elbow.

FWIW, an [n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flick+of+the+wrist%2Cflick+of+the+hand%2Cflick+of+the+finger%2Cflick+of+the+fingers&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: In the case of flicking a peanut, the arm wouldn't generally need to move at all - it's all about the thumb/finger action...

Comment: @Psmears:Does it take both hands to flick a peanut, as shown in the video? Or is it like shooting marbles, a flick of the thumb?

Comment: exactly like shooting marbles - a flick of the finger and/or thumb... (In the video he's using his other hand to hold... whatever it is he's flicking, but he could equally have put it on the table and just used the one hand.)

Comment: I was imagining the peanut was still in the shell. That's how they used to be served up in the dive bars I went to in college. Clearly there's a demi-monde  with a shelled peanut flicking ritual.

Comment: We can also *flick someone a glance*, in that case we're using our eyes!

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've never heard "flick (someone) a glance". Where have you heard this?  It sounds like something you'd find in a pulp romance.

Comment: Ngram ["flick a glance"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flick+a+glance&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @Lovii: What dictionaries?  I have never heard anyone use "flick"with "glance".

Comment: @Mari-LouA  I was on the money with my remark about it sounding like something from a pulp romance, where the writing often shows the telltale sign that a thesaurus has been consulted without regard for whether a word is used in the way the author wants to use it.  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22flick%20a%20glance%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2016,cd_max:2017&lr=lang_en

Comment: @TimR From [a dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/flick_1): to flick a glance/look at smb = to flick smb a glance/look: "_She flicked a nervous glance at him_. = _She flicked him a nervous glance._" From [another dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/flick-a-glance-look-at-somebody-something): "_Leith flicked a glance at her watch_." Also: to flick a smile at smb = to flick smb a smile. Are all these phrases unnatural to you?

Comment: @Lovii: These uses with of "flick" with "glance" seem largely confined to pulp romances.  So these attestations are not "natural" but "artificial" or "literary", and from a particular genre notorious for the copycat, formulaic nature of its diction and phraseology.  The use might enter everyday language via this route.

Comment: It's language Romano, it's what the masses use, read and speak. And if the expression–flick a glance at someone–originated in pulp romance what difference does it make? There are thousands of expressions and idioms that originated in literary works both high and low, cinematography, and in music. That's no reason to sneer at "flick a glance" Personally, I find the usage interesting.

Comment: @Mari-LouA But it is not what "the masses" *say*. It's what the masses "read" in pulp romances. It has not entered everyday speech. If and when it does, we'll know where it came from ;-)

Answer (score -1):

At best Oxford's Posted text borders on the awful, but far-too-common, example in which dictionaries cite something merely grammatical as though it had a semantic meaning. This doesn't and if there's a fault, that's Oxford's, not yours.

As here, examples cited by dictionaries are too often illustrated by proffering 'James flicked a peanut…' as though 'flicked' was different from 'chucked/flung/hurled/threw…' or anything similar. In the context of Oxford Learners' example there is no such difference… which suggests if there's a fault, its Oxford's, not yours.

To truly describe a 'flick' might be beyond me, and it's very clearly beyond the poor drudges at Oxford so please, don't let them mislead you.

To flick something does involve using both finger and thumb but that  description is not useful. Simply using finger and thumb together might be a kind of throwing, perhaps flinging; never flicking.

Using finger and thumb together would apply at least equally to throwing darts. Does anyone here think I'm going too far in saying that using finger and thumb together to throw darts describes a wholly different action, nothing like 'flicking' in the sense of peanuts? Who doubts that, please Post a separate Question.

Flicking might involve a 'hand' but only as that involves all, or at least several, fingers. We use our hands to 'chuck/fling/hurl/throw…'
balls, as for instance in baseball, cricket or rounders, basketball or netball.

Who's heard of a ball being 'flicked' in those sports, except as a special description of the unusually remarkable skill of a particular player in a given game, please speak up now!

All that said, to flick does involve '… using both finger and thumb…' but only in a very particular way so again if there's a fault, that's not your fault.

I might be putting this badly, perhaps worse than Oxford did and still:

To 'flick' specifically involves using a finger like the string of a crossbow, and the thumb rather like the trigger. Does that much make sense?

To 'flick' involves straining the finger against the thumb, until the point when the finger slips past the thumb's restraint.

Comment: I believe it is fairly common to talk about flicking a frisbee (though several other words work well.) Similarly, flicking would probably be the normal usage for both Subbuteo and Tiddly-winks, and both differ somewhat from this description.

Comment: @MikeB If somewhere like English Language & Usage you want to debate that, please Post your own Questions there!

Here in English Language Learners, what could your Comment add but confusion?

FYI no, flicking as in either Subbuteo or Tiddlywinks are perfect examples, neither differing in any way from my description.